# Python + Selenium: How to Locate new occuring Elements in while loop?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

i try to click all buttons of a specific class. The Problem is, that the buttons occur only if i have clicked buttons of the same class. i hope i can explain it clearly. it is a kind of timeline that opens up further by clicking buttons and more buttons are added to the DOM. my goal is that all buttons of a specific class are clicked, so the timeline is completely expanded.

Here is what i have tried:

```
 while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "classname")))
        button.click()

        #time.sleep(1)
        #driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    except:
        break
```

i also have tried, but it doesnt make any difference:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
while True:
    try:
        button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='classname']")))
        button.click()
    except:
        break
```

it seems that the driver cannot find the newly appearing elements, or that the loop continues before they can be found. i am very grateful for your help.

Edit: I am getting the following error

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i am getting a the following error: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: this error implies that the page/requested element is not yet loaded. have you tried increasing the waiting time between iterations?

Comment: Instead `presence_of_element_located` try with `visibility_of_element_located`

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on classes for websites you don't own.
That's one of your problems here, or it'll be in future.
Rely on something that is gonna remain static for a long time, like the text write on the button.
If u are sure that the next buttons are gonna have the same class name just storage the class name of the first button found searching for its text and use the class name further in the loop.

Make Sure that these buttons are not loaded in a iframe too, that's could be a problem.
Anyway pls post two images of the source code of the page. One before the first click, the second after you have clicked the first button.

Thanks.